# Spring Cloud API Gateway handle high volume

Tags: spring, hystrix, spring-cloud-feign

I have written the API Gateway and it uses FeignClients + Eureka to call the service end points.

Our requirement is to support at least 100 requests per second. We are using a t2.xlarge server and we are using Thread isolation. The following configurations are in the property file.

```
hystrix.threadpool.default.coreSize = 150
hystrix.command.default.execution.timeout.enabled = false
hystrix.command.default.circuitBreaker.requestVolumeThreshold = 100
```

With these configurations, we are only able to handle 20 requests per second and it's not reliable as well. So appreciate if you can advice on the strategy to achieve this or more.

Thanks,
R